# How to return int value through sql query if my conditions are met?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I return value through sql query if my conditions are met?

```
DECLARE @MyInt int;

BEGIN TRANSACTION;
    SET @MyInt = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table1 WHERE key=5);
    if (@MyInt = 5)
    Begin
        RETURN 1;
    End 
    RETURN 0;
COMMIT;
```

This is The Error I get:

***Error: A RETURN statement with a return value cannot be used in this context.***

Comment: Use select instead of return, Return works only inside a function or stored procedure

Comment: Tag properly!  MySQL <> SQL Server.  Which one is this???

Comment: @Eric this cannot be MySQL, since you cannot declare a session variable with the declare keyword.

Comment: @Shadow OP tagged both.  Thus the question.

Comment: @Eric I got that, but in this particular instance, based on the code and the error message, we can safely conclude without the OP on the product being used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you created is called an [Anonymous block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/begin-end-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) what you need is either a Select as provided by [@GordonLinoff's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55148374/460557) or you could define a [Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-function-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) with your code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SomeFunctionName (@Key Int)  
 RETURNS int  
 WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER  
BEGIN;
   SET @MyInt = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table1 WHERE key=@Key);
   if (@MyInt = 5)
   Begin
       RETURN 1;
   End 
   RETURN 0;
END;
GO;
```

And then use it as:

```
SELECT dbo.SomeFunctionName(5) AS 'someAlias';
```

Comment: Thank You Very Much, Your Answer Was Very HelpFul

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN COUNT(*) = 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM Table1
WHERE key = 5;
```

There is no reason to wrap a single `SELECT` in a transaction.  And using `return()` doesn't make sense unless you are in a stored function (or perhaps procedure).